# Remove value from data array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, html-select

I have a data array  that is used to fill three drop downs, `<select>` boxes. My question is how would I remove the same values from the array (not the array itself, but remove(or) disable the same value from the drop down)?

For example:

```
data = {
firstbox_a: ['grpA_1','grpA_2','grpA_3','grpA_4'],
firstbox_b: ['grpB_1','grpB_2','grpB_3','grpB_4'],
grpA_1: ['y','n','un','st'],
grpA_2: ['y','n','un','st'],
grpA_3: ['y','n','un','st'],
grpA_4: ['y','n','un','st'],
grpB_1: ['a','b','avg','unc'],
grpB_2: ['a','b','avg','unc'],
grpB_3: ['a','b','avg','unc'],
grpB_4: ['a','b','avg','unc']
}
```

`grpA_1` to `grpA_4` have the same values. If I select 'y' for `grpA_1`, 'y' cannot be chosen, by either disabling or removing the value from `grpA_2` to `grpA_4`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that springs to mind could be:

Attach an event to the selection of an item in the drop down list.

In the event, add a function that IF:
    Any of the other drop down lists have been selected with the same value.
    Prevent Default.

**Example**

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    // Your code goes in here :)
});
```

Comment: thanks chris for the help. I was actually using (planning on) jquery (i should have specified). the only problem i see with implementing this is each dropdown is activated(filled) by an array of values based on selections from the previous dropdown.

Comment: In JQuery this is actually very easy. I'll ammend my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood your question, based on the previous answer. I was going to use your data, but was unsure of how the lists are populated.

This code will create two lists. If an option is selected in the 2nd list, the item in the first list **with the same index** is also disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);


function onList2Changed(list2_Element, list1_Element)
{
    var i;

    for (i=0; i<list1_Element.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == list2_Element.selectedIndex)
            list1_Element.options[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
        else
            list1_Element.options[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
}

function mInit()
{
    var opt, mSel1, mSel2;
    var i, numOpts = 10;

    mSel1 = newEl('select');
    for (i=0; i<numOpts; i++)
    {
        opt = newEl('option');
        opt.appendChild( newTxt("boxA: " + (i+1)) );
        mSel1.appendChild(opt);
    }
    mSel1.setAttribute('size', i);
    document.body.appendChild(mSel1);

    mSel2 = newEl('select');
    for (i=0; i<numOpts; i++)
    {
        opt = newEl('option');
        opt.appendChild( newTxt("disable BoxA option: " + (i+1)) );
        mSel2.appendChild(opt);
    }
    mSel2.addEventListener('change', myFunc);

    function myFunc()
    {
        onList2Changed(mSel2, mSel1);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(mSel2);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. its actually three lists. firstbox_a, and _b is one dropdown. grpA 1-4 and grpB 1-4 is the second dropdown. the values (y, n, avg ...etc) are the third dropdown. its the third dropdown that has the corresponding values being disabled/removed. So if 'avg' is selected once, 'avg' cannot be selected again.

Comment: No worries. I've read your comment above about 4 or 5 times, yet am sorry to report that I can't really make heads nor tails of it - that is to say I still can't work out how the ***data*** object corresponds to the data that each list holds. If you would edit your question to include the code that populates the three lists, I'll be provide an answer that is more useful. :)

Comment: @PSCoder - A +1 for being childish and predictable. I'd realized it was likely you that downlvoted this over 25 minutes ago. You just keep on point-whoring. It's obviously working well for you so far!